# How to insert 11-13 gr_numbers at a time on click button using pl/sql loop which is getting from select query block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to Insert those all gr_numbers which is getting from APP_USER,image of result is attached  approx 11-13 gr_numbers fetched. my objective is
i have a button i want to write a process when i will click button it will insert those all gr_numbers using loop
on click button whenever i click the button.

Here is my Gr_numbers Result image which is getting from select block. which is required to insert all gr_number on click button 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsMt7.png)

Code Have Bugs/Errors it will not insert all gr_numbers on click button

```
declare
vtm NUMBER(38);

-- vtm student.gr_number%TYPE;
tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
BEGIN
tab := apex_util.string_to_table (vtm);
SELECT s.gr_number into vtm
FROM student s
left join class_time ct on ct.class_id=s.class_id and
instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
where upper(trim(ct.class_id)) = upper(trim(:APP_USER)) and s.gr_number is not null
and is_active_flg = 'Y';

dbms_output.put_line(vtm); 
for i in vtm..tab.count loop
begin

insert into STUDENT_CLASS_ATTEND(gr_number, student_id, PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG, attend_date,                                    period_start_dt, period_end_dt, PERIOD_DURATION,  course_name, class_time, branch_id, shift_id, teacher_id, class_id,  marked_by,     course_id, class_uid)
                          select vtm, student_id, next_day_flg,        to_date(UPPER(:P7_ATTEND_DT_TMP),'DD-MON-YYYY'), prd_start_tm,   prd_end_tm,    prd_diff_minutes, course_name, class_time, branch_id, shift_id, teacher_id, class_id, :v_employee_id, course_id, class_uid
from (
WITH
class_start_tm as
(select s.gr_number, 
        s.class_id, 
        s.class_time as student_class_time_list, 
        ct.class_time, 
        ct.seq, 
        to_date(upper(:P7_ATTEND_DT_TMP)||' '||ct.class_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') as class_first_tm
from student s
join class_time ct on s.class_id=ct.class_id
where s.gr_number =:P7_GR_TMP
and ct.seq=1
)
,tm as(
Select s.gr_number,
       cl.duration_minutes,
       t.class_first_tm,
       to_date(UPPER(:P7_ATTEND_DT_TMP)||' '||to_char(cl.start_time,'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') as prd_start_tm,
       to_date(UPPER(:P7_ATTEND_DT_TMP)||' '||to_char(cl.start_time,'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM')+ interval '30' minute as prd_end_tm,
       (case when to_date(UPPER(:P7_ATTEND_DT_TMP)||' '||to_char(cl.start_time,'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') < t.class_first_tm then 'Y' else 'N' end) next_day_flg
from calender_24hr cl
join student s on instr(s.class_time,cl.time_12hr)>0 and s.gr_number=:P7_GR_TMP
join class_start_tm t on t.gr_number=s.gr_number
)
,tm1 as (
select gr_number,
       duration_minutes,
--       class_first_tm,
       (case when next_day_flg='Y' then prd_start_tm+1 else prd_start_tm end) prd_start_tm,
       (case when next_day_flg='Y' then prd_end_tm+1 else prd_end_tm end) prd_end_tm,
       next_day_flg
from tm
order by (case when next_day_flg='Y' then prd_start_tm+1 else prd_start_tm end)
)
,tm2 as (
select gr_number,
       max(next_day_flg) AS next_day_flg, 
       min(prd_start_tm) AS prd_start_tm, 
       max(prd_end_tm) AS prd_end_tm, 
       round((max(prd_end_tm)-min(prd_start_tm))*24*60,0)  AS prd_diff_minutes,
       sum(duration_minutes) actual_minutes,
       round((max(prd_end_tm)-min(prd_start_tm))*24*60,0) - sum(duration_minutes) as gap_minutes
from tm1
 group by gr_number
) 
select st.gr_number, st.student_id, tm.next_day_flg, prd_start_tm, prd_end_tm, tm.prd_diff_minutes, 
       tm.actual_minutes, tm.gap_minutes, 
       st.course as course_id, cr.course_name, 
       cl.class_uid, st.class_id, st.class_time, 
       st.branch_id, st.shift_id, cl.teacher_id
from tm2 tm
join student st on tm.gr_number=st.gr_number
left join course cr on cr.course_id = st.course
left join class cl  on cl.class_id = st.class_id
);


exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('there is no data..');

end;

end loop;
commit;
end;
```

But Error Happened in initialization image is below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qt8.png)

Comment: How is this any different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172495/no-data-found-or-too-many-rows-exception-error-occured-during-bulk-record-insert)? They appear identcal.

Comment: @Belayer this is my detail query problem is that my this query return **13 gr_no rows** which i want to insert on table on click button process using **loop/cursor**  but it will not adjust in vtm variable.
SELECT s.gr_number into vtm
FROM student s
left join class_time ct on ct.class_id=s.class_id and
instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
where upper(trim(ct.class_id)) = upper(trim(:APP_USER)) and s.gr_number is not null
and is_active_flg = 'Y';

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gr_number already in a table, then this should just be a standard INSERT-SELECT statement

```
insert into STUDENT_CLASS_ATTEND(
  gr_number, student_id, PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG, 
  attend_date, period_start_dt, period_end_dt, 
  PERIOD_DURATION, course_name, class_time, 
  branch_id, shift_id, teacher_id, class_id, 
marked_by, course_id, class_uid)
select  
  s.gr_number, :P7_STUDENT_ID, :P7_PERIOD_NEXT_DAY_FLG, 
  to_date(UPPER(:P7_ATTEND_DATE),'DD-MON-YYYY'), :P7_PERIOD_START_DT, :P7_PERIOD_END_DT, 
  :P7_PERIOD_DURATION, :P7_COURSE_NAME, :P7_CLASS_TIME, 
  :P7_BRANCH_ID, :P7_SHIFT_ID, :P7_TEACHER_ID, :P7_CLASS_ID, 
  :v_employee_id, :P7_COURSE_ID, :P7_CLASS_UID
FROM student s
left join class_time ct on ct.class_id=s.class_id and
instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
where upper(trim(ct.class_id)) = upper(trim(:APP_USER)) and s.gr_number is not null
and is_active_flg = 'Y'
```

Comment: @Conor McDonald I get Gr_numbers using select query now bulk 12-13 records i want to insert on one click

Comment: Bro check my above Query