# No data found or too many rows exception error occured during bulk record insertion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have Write a pl/sql process to insert bulk record which is getting from select statement after 
first begin but i will raised error and not insert any record help me to fix the error during 
insertion
How to Insert my 11 gr_numbers/rows which is returned from select statement
It Shows **No Data found** or **More then rows fetched** exceptions occour. Image has attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaKbX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeiJL.png)

```
DECLARE
    vtm   NUMBER;
    tab   apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
BEGIN
    tab := apex_util.string_to_table(vtm);
    SELECT
        s.gr_number
    INTO vtm
    FROM
        student      s
        LEFT JOIN class_time   ct ON ct.class_id = s.class_id
                                   AND instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
    WHERE
        upper(TRIM(ct.class_id)) = upper(TRIM(:app_user))
        AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
        AND is_active_flg = 'Y'
        AND gr_number = vtm;

    --dbms_output.put_line(vtm); 
    --for i in 1..tab.count loop

    FOR i IN 1..tab.count LOOP INSERT INTO student_class_attend (
        gr_number,
        student_id,
        period_next_day_flg,
        attend_date,
        period_start_dt,
        period_end_dt,
        period_duration,
        course_name,
        class_time,
        branch_id,
        shift_id,
        teacher_id,
        class_id,
        marked_by,
        course_id,
        class_uid
    )
        SELECT
            gr_number,
            student_id,
            next_day_flg,
            to_date(upper(:p7_attend_dt_tmp), 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
            prd_start_tm,
            prd_end_tm,
            prd_diff_minutes,
            course_name,
            class_time,
            branch_id,
            shift_id,
            teacher_id,
            class_id,
            :v_employee_id,
            course_id,
            class_uid
        FROM
            (
                WITH class_start_tm AS (
                    SELECT
                        s.gr_number,
                        s.class_id,
                        s.class_time AS student_class_time_list,
                        ct.class_time,
                        ct.seq,
                        to_date(upper(:p7_attend_dt_tmp)
                                || ' '
                                || ct.class_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') AS class_first_tm
                    FROM
                        student      s
                        JOIN class_time   ct ON s.class_id = ct.class_id
                    WHERE
                        s.gr_number = :p7_gr_tmp
                        AND ct.seq = 1
                ), tm AS (
                    SELECT
                        s.gr_number,
                        cl.duration_minutes,
                        t.class_first_tm,
                        to_date(upper(:p7_attend_dt_tmp)
                                || ' '
                                || to_char(cl.start_time, 'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') AS prd_start_tm,
                        to_date(upper(:p7_attend_dt_tmp)
                                || ' '
                                || to_char(cl.start_time, 'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE AS prd_end_tm,
                        (
                            CASE
                                WHEN to_date(upper(:p7_attend_dt_tmp)
                                             || ' '
                                             || to_char(cl.start_time, 'HHMIAM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HHMIAM') < t.class_first_tm THEN
                                    'Y'
                                ELSE
                                    'N'
                            END
                        ) next_day_flg
                    FROM
                        calender_24hr    cl
                        JOIN student          s ON instr(s.class_time, cl.time_12hr) > 0
                                          AND s.gr_number = :p7_gr_tmp
                        JOIN class_start_tm   t ON t.gr_number = s.gr_number
                ), tm1 AS (
                    SELECT
                        gr_number,
                        duration_minutes,
--       class_first_tm,
                        (
                            CASE
                                WHEN next_day_flg = 'Y' THEN
                                    prd_start_tm + 1
                                ELSE
                                    prd_start_tm
                            END
                        ) prd_start_tm,
                        (
                            CASE
                                WHEN next_day_flg = 'Y' THEN
                                    prd_end_tm + 1
                                ELSE
                                    prd_end_tm
                            END
                        ) prd_end_tm,
                        next_day_flg
                    FROM
                        tm
                    ORDER BY
                        (
                            CASE
                                WHEN next_day_flg = 'Y' THEN
                                    prd_start_tm + 1
                                ELSE
                                    prd_start_tm
                            END
                        )
                ), tm2 AS (
                    SELECT
                        gr_number,
                        MAX(next_day_flg) AS next_day_flg,
                        MIN(prd_start_tm) AS prd_start_tm,
                        MAX(prd_end_tm) AS prd_end_tm,
                        round((MAX(prd_end_tm) - MIN(prd_start_tm)) * 24 * 60, 0) AS prd_diff_minutes,
                        SUM(duration_minutes) actual_minutes,
                        round((MAX(prd_end_tm) - MIN(prd_start_tm)) * 24 * 60, 0) - SUM(duration_minutes) AS gap_minutes
                    FROM
                        tm1
                    GROUP BY
                        gr_number
                )
                SELECT
                    st.gr_number,
                    st.student_id,
                    tm.next_day_flg,
                    prd_start_tm,
                    prd_end_tm,
                    tm.prd_diff_minutes,
                    tm.actual_minutes,
                    tm.gap_minutes,
                    st.course AS course_id,
                    cr.course_name,
                    cl.class_uid,
                    st.class_id,
                    st.class_time,
                    st.branch_id,
                    st.shift_id,
                    cl.teacher_id
                FROM
                    tm2       tm
                    JOIN student   st ON tm.gr_number = st.gr_number
                    LEFT JOIN course    cr ON cr.course_id = st.course
                    LEFT JOIN class     cl ON cl.class_id = st.class_id
            );

    END LOOP;

--exception 
--when too_many_rows then

EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        SELECT
            s.gr_number
        INTO vtm
        FROM
            student      s
            LEFT JOIN class_time   ct ON ct.class_id = s.class_id
                                       AND instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
        WHERE
            upper(TRIM(ct.class_id)) = upper(TRIM(:app_user))
            AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
            AND is_active_flg = 'Y'
            AND gr_number = vtm;

        dbms_output.put_line('Error, rows = ' || vtm);
        end;
END loop;

COMMIT;

end;
```

Comment: If either of the answers solved your issue then please accept the answer. If not then what is the remaining issue. Please don't just leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01403` (No data found) happens when your query returns nothing and you try do pass it to variable via `INTO`.

`ORA-01422` (Too many rows) happens when your query returns more than 1 row that you are trying to fit at `INTO`.

You are handling the `no_data_found` from the first `SELECT` query but you are not handling `too_many_rows` from the first query. If your first `SELECT` query throws an `no_data_found` exception, it will be handled from the `EXCEPTION`, otherwise if it throws an `too_many_rows` exception than it will fail as your second image.

So where is the `no_data_found` exception happening? Probably from you second `SELECT` query.

You should loop the first `SELECT` query in order to avoid a `no_data_found` or a `too_many_rows` and make sure that your second `SELECT` query returns always 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

The no_data_found is actually being raised twice. The first time during the initial select (the 2nd statement after begin). The second time by the exception procedure handling the first occurrence. This occurs because your exception handler attempts the exact same query. Thus the exact same result.  
So why is the no_data_found raised the first time. You define the local variable vtm as number, but you do not initialize the value. This makes its value NULL. You then go on to use vtm in the where clause of the select statement :(AND gr_number = vtm;) This predicate will only return NULL thus making the entire where clause always false, which means no data satisfies the where condition.  
Correction: Well I don't know. You didn't provide sample data nor parameter values. However, somehow you must initialize the variable vtm to an existing gr_number (that may NOT be the only cause) or remove the variable from the query. Then again perhaps removing it is what caused your "too many rows" exception.  
If that is the case then you need to convert "select ... into ..." and and the loop from processing a collection to processing the cursor.

```
declare
    gr_cursor cursor is 
       ( select s.gr_number
           from student      s
           left join class_time   ct 
                  on ct.class_id = s.class_id
                 and instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
          where upper(trim(ct.class_id)) = upper(trim(:app_user))
            and s.gr_number is not null
            and is_active_flg = 'Y'
            and gr_number = vtm 
       ); 

begin
    for grc in gr_cursor
    loop 
      insert into student_class_attend (
        ... ;
    end loop;

    commit; 
end;
```

Disclaimer: I did NOT verify the variables vtm, tab are not in the expansion for the insert, nor attempt other changes, if any, within that expansion. But there may very well be some needed.

Comment: it give error                                                                                                
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
ORA-06550: line 5, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LEFT" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , group having intersect minus start union where connect
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: Sorry mixed up Oracle vs Postgres cursor description. Try "  cursor gr_cursor is ... "